# Break python assignment into multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x, pep8, flake8

What would be the cleanest way to break this into multiple lines following PEP8's guidelines?

```py
long_name, longer_name, even_longer_name = list_to_break_into_long_names
```

I could think of

```py
long_name, longer_name, even_longer_name = \
    list_to_break_into_long_names
```

but a backslash raises `C092 prefer implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets, and braces as opposed to a backslash`. I'm unable to think of a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to use parentheses:

```
long_name, longer_name, even_longer_name = (
    list_to_break_into_long_names)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using parentheses

```
(
    long_name,
    longer_name,
    even_longer_name,
) = list_to_break_into_long_names
```

Also you might consider using a tool like python-black to just make formatting automatic and just accept the way it does it. The disadvantage is that it may not quite be the way you would think best. The advantage is that it does it reasonably well and you can spend less time thinking about cleaning up your code formatting.

Comment: This seems like a clean way to do it and hence I've upvoted it, but the other answer gets the job done for me in lesser sentences (i.e., compact) which is the only reason why I've selected it.